# Table format interactive Chart javascript

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, charts, html5-canvas

I am trying to build an interactive chart which is the form of a table that basically tells the user if a service was up or down on a particular day of month of a year. If the user clicks on the field it opens a new url and tells more about that status.

I was thinking of using d3.js charts but did not find any charts ? Is there something that already exist that i can use ? Never was able to find a chart in the form of a table.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a job for [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: A table is not really a chart visualization, per se. You might be better just using javascript itself for this.

Comment: Grids/tables are used for visualizing data in several ways. Check out http://www.datavizcatalogue.com/

Dataviz expert Stephen Few also states that tables are more effective than most pie charts. http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf

Comment: @Merrily I didn't debate their merits, only whether D3 is the right framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to accomplish this with one of the grid widgets out there. If you'd like to use a charting library, here's an example of [an interactive grid](http://www.zingchart.com/playground/run/542315302d1ca) in ZingChart.

ZingChart is modular, so you can just [download a custom build](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/build-generator/) with the Core and Grid modules to keep it super light. We used the [label_click API method](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/api-events/#zingchart__events__label_click) to open a new window.

```
    zingchart.label_click=function(p){
        if (p.text=="Adobe Ideas"){
            window.open("https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-ideas/id364617858?mt=8");
        }
        if (p.text=="Notability"){
            window.open("http://www.gingerlabs.com/");
        }
    };
```

Make sure that the "flat" attribute is set to 0 when styling the cells.

I'm part of the ZingChart team, so if you have any questions, feel free to reach out!